# Jetpack Navigation: Popping non top entry

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Suppose I've three pages. `Home`, `Detail`, and `Watch`, and consider I've the below navigation stack.

`Home -> Detail -> Watch -> Detail`.

Now I want to open a new `Watch` page, but the existing one should be removed from the current stack. Which mean, the resulting stack should be

`Home -> Detail -> Detail -> Watch`.

Is it possible to implement using Jetpack Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you talk about [this navigation component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) when talking about "Jetpack Navigation" then you have the possibility to add navigation options.

You can e.g. make sure that there is only one copy of your `Watch` page on the back stack with `launchSingleTop`. It might not manipulate the back stack in a way that you described above because deleting `Watch` out of the back stack seems a bit unusual.

However, you might get the behaviour you need with those additional navigation options.

```
// Pop everything up to the "home" destination off the back stack before
// navigating to the "friendslist" destination
navController.navigate("friendslist") {
    popUpTo("home")
}

// Pop everything up to and including the "home" destination off
// the back stack before navigating to the "friendslist" destination
navController.navigate("friendslist") {
    popUpTo("home") { inclusive = true }
}

// Navigate to the "search” destination only if we’re not already on
// the "search" destination, avoiding multiple copies on the top of the
// back stack
navController.navigate("search") {
    launchSingleTop = true
}
```